# 2 monitors on GTX 690 + 1 monitor on DisplayLink = "Unable to save display settings"

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, displaylink

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I have three monitors:

- one monitor is connected to one of my Nvidia GTX 690's DVI ports.
- one monitor is connected to a USB port using a [DisplayLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink) DVI > USB adapter

Everything works fine. I want to connect a third monitor to another DVI port of my Nvidia GTX 690. The third monitor is detected:

[image]

However, I cannot extend or clone desktop to this third monitor: when I try to do so I get the error message "Unable to save display settings".

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, connect the third monitor to a DVI port of the Nvidia GTX 690. I used those 2 DVI ports, but from what I read any port should be fine:

[image]

Then, should should go to the Nvidia settings (Control panel > Nvidia). At first they won't be many options:

[image]

That's because you're using the DisplayLink driver. You should disconnect the monitor using the DisplayLink adapter, and if needed stop the DisplayLink service. Once done, the Nvidia settings will have more options:

[image]

You should disable the multi-GPU mode:

[image]

Then select the two monitors connected to the GTX 690's DVI ports:

[image]

Then restart the DisplayLink service and re-connect the monitor to the DisplayLink adapter. The "Unable to save display settings" error message should not appear anymore.

---

Note that you might be able to keep the multi-GPU on and simply connect to other ports:

[image]